# Avoiding input in the socket read output - Python

Tags: python, bash, sockets, stdout, stdin

I have the following `recv_size` method:

```
def recv_size(self, socket, n=8192, timeout=0.25):
    """

    :param socket:
    :param n:
    :param timeout:
    :return:
    """
    socket.setblocking(0)
    data = ''
    begin = time.time()
    while True:
        # if you got some data, then break after wait sec
        if data and time.time() - begin > timeout:
            break
        # if you got no data at all, wait a little longer
        elif time.time() - begin > timeout*2:
            break
        try:
            data = socket.recv(n)
            if data:
                sys.stdout.write(data)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                begin = time.time()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except:
            pass
```

I'm sending information to the `socket` via `sendall()`:

```
exec_id = client.exec_start(command)
while True:
    recv_size(socket)
    container_info = client.inspect_container(container)
    if exec_id['Id'] in container_info['ExecIDs']:
        input_value = sys.stdin.readline()
        socket.sendall(input_value)
    else:
        break
```

So when I enter a command line `/bin/bash` I'm able to start sending information to the remote terminal. However, I'm always getting the `input_value` in the return message:

```
root@so1:# echo "hello"
echo "hello"
hello
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Needs clarification.  You want to hide the locally typed input or the remote output?  I'm confused either way.

Comment: @selbie I want to ride the locally typed input. What's happening there is when I type the command and sent it thru the connection it's echoing it back when I read the response. I don't want it to echo.